# trouble with quotes in qmake

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

I have a problem with qmake on qt creator. This is the part of my .pro file that is messing up:

```
CUDA_DIR = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v7.0"
SYSTEM_NAME = Win32

# library directories
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME\

# Add the necessary libraries
CUDA_LIBS= -lcuda -lcudart
LIBS += $$CUDA_LIBS
```

Here is what I expect to get:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\Win32\cuda.lib" 
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\Win32\cudart.lib"
```

But, this is what actually I get:

```
""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\Win32"\cuda.lib" 
""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\Win32"\cudart.lib"
```

**UPDATE:** Okay, I fixed this part. I changed it to this line and it fixed:

```
LIBS += -L"$$CUDA_DIR/lib/Win32" -lcuda \
    -L"$$CUDA_DIR/lib/Win32" -lcudartv
```

Now in Makefile.Debug I have this:

```
LIBS = /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\Win32"
       "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\Win32\cuda.lib"
       "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\Win32\cudart.lib"
```

Now when it get passed to a custom build process (CUDA) it removes the double quotes!!!!

Any idea how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try escaping the quotes, if you need to preserve them.

Comment: qmake doublequotes string that is already doublequoted? I even got the stranger thing.. I had <<INCLUDEPATH= b c "d" "e" "f">> and got <<-Ib -Ic -I""d" "e" "f"">>.
Can any one explain it?

Answer (score -2):

I just re-installed nvidia toolkit with a different path with no spaces. That fixed my issue.